# MS Access: count the name

Tags: sql, ms-access-2013

How to count the student name and display all the data

```
ID Name      Subject
1  Jack      English
2  Tiffany   English
3  Ben       Mathematics
4  Tiffany   Science
5  Jack      Mathematics
```

Then the return of the result for the output will show the subject taken of each person.

```
ID Name      Subject       [Subject Taken]
1  Jack      English       2
2  Tiffany   English       2
3  Ben       Mathematics   1
4  Tiffany   Science       2
5  Jack      Mathematics   2
```

Comment: Why *without using group by*?

Comment: Correlated sub-query?

Comment: Because i tried using group by but then the subject taken for the data will all be 1 instead of 2

Answer (score 2):

you could achieve this with a subquery but not without a group by. make a group by first then join that group by with the original table.

SubQuery Group by result

```
Name    CountOfSubject
Ben     1
jack    2
Tiffany 2
```

-

```
 SELECT SubQuery.Name, Table1.Subject, SubQuery.CountOfSubject
 FROM 
            ( SELECT Table1.Name, 
                     Count(Table1.Subject) AS CountOfSubject
              FROM Table1
              GROUP BY Table1.Name) AS SubQuery 
 INNER JOIN Table1 ON SubQuery.Name = Table1.Name;
```

result

```
Name    Subject     CountOfSubject
jack    English     2
Tiffany English     2
Ben     Mathematics 1
Tiffany Science     2
jack    Mathematics 2
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if my student name is in student table and subject is in subject table. How can i link them up together?

Comment: if they are in separate tables there should be a Foreign key to link them together.